# How do I get the latest Java JRE version?

Tags: 14.04, 32-bit

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and I need the latest version of Java JRE to run certain games but I have the old version and I do not know how I can update it. I tried downloading it from https://java.com/download but I couldn't rub the downloaded file, Also tried looking at other people's questions but I couldn't really understand them.The error I get is "the application requires a Java runtime environment 1.6.0"
Here's a screen shot of the error: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sh7GU.png

Comment: Do you want an OpenJDK JRE or an Oracle one?

Comment: I don't really know, i'm just trying to solve the error "the application requires a Java runtime environment 1.6.0"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## WebUpd8

Webupd8 offers a [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java) on Launchpad which offers Java installers for all current Ubuntu releases.

PPA description:

```
Oracle Java (JDK) Installer (automatically downloads and installs Oracle JDK7 / JDK8 / JDK9). There are no actual Java files in this PPA.

More info (and Ubuntu installation instructions):
- for Oracle Java 7: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html
- for Oracle Java 8: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

Debian installation instructions:
- Oracle Java 7: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-in-debian.html
- Oracle Java 8: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-in-debian.html

Important!!! For now, you should continue to use Java 8 because Oracle Java 9 is available as an early access release (it should be released in 2016)! You should only use Oracle Java 9 if you explicitly need it, because it may contain bugs and it might not include the latest security patches! Also, some Java options were removed in JDK9, so you may encounter issues with various Java apps. More information and installation instructions (Ubuntu / Linux Mint / Debian): http://www.webupd8.org/2015/02/install-oracle-java-9-in-ubuntu-linux.html
```

In case you need Java 8 - simple do as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Comment: I followed the steps but still while running the games I get the error that I don't have Java 1.6.0

Comment: "The application requires a Java runtime environment 1.6.0"

Comment: @HamzaKC, Type `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default` to fix that. There's a script in that ppa which sets Java 8 as default, installing it should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `default-jre` which is a simple package basically equivalent to openjdk-jre:

**Verify if Java is already Installed**

As you tried many things before you'll want to check if Java is not already installed

```
java -version
```

If it returns `The program java can be found in the following packages` you can move forward to the next steps.

**Installing default JRE**

First, update the package index

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install JRE with `apt-get`

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

**Installing JDK**

You may want to install JDK which is usually needed to compile Java applications

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

You can as well install other versions of JDK like `OpenJDK` and `Oracle JDK`

Comment: How do I completely remove the previous Java installed so I can install the new one?

Comment: I don't understand .. If it's Installed why you want to install it again ?

Comment: I'm just trying to get rid of the error, other threads show that re-installing a newer version fixes the issue.

Comment: what's the output of `java -version`

Comment: java version "1.8.0-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-ea-b108)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.0-b50, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing openjdk-6 version from [software center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/openjdk-6-jre) or directly via terminal like this

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
```

Hope that helps.

Regards Douglas

Comment: I have installed java with the help of the other answers but the error wont go away.

Comment: two things.. if you have jre-6, ensure its the default jre in the system.  you can check with the -version argument but if its not, set it using the **update-alternatives** command

Comment: so long as you have java 1.6 installed.. just make sure its the default jre in the system

Comment: How do I make sure its the default jre in the system?

Comment: `sudo update-alternatives --config java` and type in the [XX] number listed next to the version you wish to set as default then enter

Answer (score -2):

Have you already tried to install openjdk-7-jre?

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

Comment: When I tried that I got this:
"Unable to locate package openjdk-9-jre"

Comment: There is no such package in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @HamzaKC Replace the 9 with 8.

Comment: 8 is not there as well. ))

Comment: It's the same error.

Comment: It's either 6 or 7.

Comment: Both are in the repos.